# How can I change the default Unity keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, putty

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 and it works fine.

But I have a little problem. I need to use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) and it uses <kbd>F10</kbd> as a shortcut to a function, but Unity intercepts it as a shrtcut, so I cannot access this function.

How I can change this shortcut in Unity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Go to 'Unity Plugin', choose General tab (the default tab)
3. Change *Key to open the first panel menu* as you like to free your shortcut:

   [image]

Some more key bindings are in General Options, tab Key bindings. I was using CCSM 0.9.11.2, in future versions of CCSM these options can change.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what exact software you want to have and then I may help you in better way. 
nevertheless you can search for system settings and there you will find keyboard shortcuts.. may be there you can change the settings.

Comment: The software that i use is a ERP, it's use the software putty to make a conection ssh between PHP and ssh.