# How can I change Unity's shortcuts programmatically?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz

I am trying to [block system shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/q/862957/69674) while using certain shortcut-heavy applications. That already works fine with shortcuts that are accessible via `dconf` and `gsettings`. However, I can not find the shortcuts defined by Unity/Compiz anywhere in `(d|g)conf-editor`; I mean those that are shown when holding <kbd>Super</kbd>.

While they can be [changed using the Compiz config settings manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38024/how-can-i-change-the-default-unity-keyboard-shortcut), CCSM does not seem to provide a command-line interface.

How can I programmatically (re)set Unity's/Compiz' top-level keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Whatever is in CCSM is frequently is in dconf , so doing `dconf watch /` and then toggling those shortcuts on / off will tell you which schemas manage them.  Not everything is in dconf though, some shortcuts i think are hard-coded into Unity.

Comment: Some compiz plugins which interface wiith shortcuts can be disabled, but i personally wouldn't recommend. Can be done but just not a good idea in my experience

Comment: @Serg Thanks for the hint. I tried for ALT+F1; turns out the default state is "enabled, no entry in `dconf`" but when you change it, an entry is created. No wonder I couldn't find any binding in `dconf-editor`... Blerg, this seems to be ugly... (I can't find ALT+` in CCSM; where else can I look?)

Comment: [Oh, my...](http://askubuntu.com/a/132315/69674)

Comment: Yep, that's what it is. May I ask, is using Unity absolutely necessary ? Have you considered switching to another desktop environment ?

Comment: Define "absolutely necessary"; it's currently the path of least resistance. And the list of alternatives is very long. Personally, I'm not averse to switching to something robust, usable, and (in this context) more easily configurable via CLI. What would you recommend?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, your main goal is to make IDE shortcuts work. Simple solution I personally would take is to switch to non-GNOME based desktop, which won't respond to the shortcuts.  I don't mind minimalism so `blackbox` or `openbox` personally would be my choice, although these are somewhat of "acquired taste" so to speak.  Controlling them via command line can be done as well with a couple tools.  I'd write something similar as Jacob, but disabling god knows how many  shortcuts is an overkill

Comment: @Serg Well, programming is not *all* I do with the machine, so some overall comfort is appreciated. I guess I'll look around.